# New-SPWebApplication application pool account is not found

Tags: 2010, powershell, web-application, application-pool

I am trying to create a new web application using PowerShell. I keep getting the error application pool account is not found! How do I solve this?

I tried adding the new web application to DefaultAppPool as follows:

```
New-SPWebApplication -Name "Test WebApp" -ApplicationPool "DefaultAppPool" -ApplicationPoolAccount (Get-SPManagedAccount "WIN2K8R2SPTEST\Administrator")
```

But the Cmdlet Get-SPManagedAccount seems to return an empty string. I also tried to change the `ApplicationPool` to SharePoint 80.

I am running SharePoint Foundation 2010 on a standalone installation. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who need the solution: Refer to the answer from [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10932021/185655) for the same question. First I needed to create a managed account since I didn't have one. And then use the `New-SPWebApplication` cmdlet to create a new webapplication.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

> New-SPWebApplication -Name "Test WebApp" -Port 80 -URL
>   "http://testwebapp" -ApplicationPool "TestWebAppPool"
>   -ApplicationPoolAccount (Get-SPManagedAccount "WIN2K8R2SPTEST\Administrator")

This will create a new web application with a new application pool account which sharepoint will register itself and map it to the port 80. You wont need to modify any settings in IIS for this.

Just ensure your port 80 is free and there are no previous SharePoint or IIS site is mapped to it.

Comment: I already have a share point web application running on port 80. Initially, i tried with a port number specified.. but after reading the docs I found that port is optional and a random port is assigned when creating the new web application.

Comment: Its is rather advised that you specify a port number larger than 3000 and create a web application on that port.